# PHP htaccess instead of $_GET

Tags: php

Im trying to make a referal system for my sighnup on my website. My current htaccsess file is below

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?page=$1
```

Is there a way of doing /refferall/Something instead of just `/Something` but keeping the normal `/Something` as well? My attempt below at the referral one. 
But it just reported:

Object not found!
   The requested URL was not found on this server.
   If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
   If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404
   127.0.0.1 
   Apache/2.4.4 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1e PHP/5.5.3

========================================================

My attempted htaccess of `/referall/something`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)referal/$1 index.php?refferal=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/referall/$1 index.php?refferal=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)referall/$1 index.php?refferal=$1
```

Full, With both

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?page=$1

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)referal/$1 index.php?refferal=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/referall/$1 index.php?refferal=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)referall/$1 index.php?refferal=$1
```

Comment: I note that you use both referal and refferal in you htaccess. Referal is obvious a typo but it could cause problems..

Answer (score 2):

`([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)` means 1 ore more characters (of the specified type within the brackets).

What you need is the following htaccess (optimized the existing part a bit)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^referal/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?referral=$1
```

Note: you have some types in referral (it's single f, single l).